# Changing the color of the following image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, background

What I'm trying to do is change the color of the following image to something around **#21190E**. I've tried using the Hue/Saturation, Color Replacer, etc. tools, but none worked well.

[image]

Do I change the current color to another so that I can get the results I want?
.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#21190E is pretty much a black. Okay it's a very, very dark brown.

- Simply create a new layer.
- Fill the new layer with #21190E
- Set the new layer blending mode to "Color"

[image: darker brown]